# Creating new pandas column from weighted values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns, composite

I'm trying to create a new column by totalling the weighted values in earlier columns.

example

```
 v1    v2   v3  
  1    2    3
  4    3    6
  3    2    1

weights = [0.801,0.796,0.637]
```

I would like to multiply v1 by weights[0], then v2 by weights[1] etc and create a new column that is the total of these operations

so that the output would be

```
 v1       v2      v3    v_tot 
0.801   1.592   -1.911  0.482
3.204   2.388   -3.822  1.77
2.403   1.592   -0.637  3.358
```

I have tried reating a new df

```
data2 = data3.mul(weights_a)
```

and this works, but when I try to create a new column

```
data2['v_tot'] = data2.loc[:,:].sum()
```

the new column is created but it's full of nan values.

can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: The columns in the original data set are all floats.

Comment: why negative values in v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = """
 v1    v2   v3  
  1    2    3
  4    3    6
  3    2    1
"""
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True)

weights = [0.801,0.796,0.637]

df['v_tot'] = (df * weights).sum(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
   v1  v2  v3  v_tot
0   1   2   3  4.304
1   4   3   6  9.414
2   3   2   1  4.632
```

P.S. And if you want to have a DataFrame with weighted values as well:

```
dfw = df * weights
dfw['v_tot'] = dfw.sum(axis=1)
dfw
```

Output:

```
      v1     v2     v3  v_tot
0  0.801  1.592  1.911  4.304
1  3.204  2.388  3.822  9.414
2  2.403  1.592  0.637  4.632
```

Comment: That worked, I was missing the (axis = 1) component. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and you probably also don't need the `.loc[:,:]` (it works with it, but it doesn't add anything)

Answer (score 2):

(not sure why are there negative values in `v3`)try:

```
df_new=df.mul(weights,axis=1)
df_new['v_tot']=df_new.sum(axis=1)
print(df_new)

      v1     v2     v3  v_tot
0  0.801  1.592  1.911  4.304
1  3.204  2.388  3.822  9.414
2  2.403  1.592  0.637  4.632
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data2['v_tot'] = data2.sum(axis=1)
```